# How disable JavaFX Text

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

How disable JavaFX Text

```
Text t = new Text();

t.setText("This is a text sample");

t.setDisable(true); //it does not work
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense.  Text is just text, it doesn't do anything, you can't interact with it.  There is nothing to disable.  What would you expect disabled text to do?

Comment: Nothing, just indicate the user that are disabled x options, with a Label works, only that a label does not allow me to format the text, so I use a Text

Comment: I'm not sure how text provides more format options than a label, but I'll try to  answer your question as best I can.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

You can style Text visually, so that it looks disabled, if you wish.  The solution below binds the opacity setting to the disabled setting of the text.

[image: disabled]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DisabledText extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Text enabledText = new Text("Enabled");

        Text disabledText = new Text("Disabled");
        disabledText.opacityProperty().bind(
                Bindings.when(
                        disabledText.disabledProperty())
                        .then(0.4)
                        .otherwise(1)
        );
        disabledText.setDisable(true);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, enabledText, disabledText);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**Notes**

You might be able to accomplish this through CSS as well rather than a binding, I just didn't try that option.

In general, many times you are usually better off using a Label then Text for a lot of things as it includes more flexibility and functionality.

**Background**

Even though the user can't interact directly with text, so disabling text really has no effect, I guess what you are looking for is that the text look like other things when they are disabled.

Normally what happens when a control such as menu item or button is disabled, is that the CSS pseudo-class `:disabled` is set on the control.  When this occurs, the default modena.css stylesheet for JavaFX 8 will modify the opacity for the control to `-fx-opacity: 0.4;`.  This changes the visual look for the control so that it appears as though it is grayed out, as the low opacity makes the control looks faded.

Text is built to be a base drawing shape.  Base drawing shapes in Java deliberately don't rely on CSS (though CSS can be used with them if needed - see the [CSS reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape) for info on what default CSS rules apply to shapes).  If your scene doesn't use any layout panes or controls, then the standard modena.css stylesheet will not be loaded and CSS processing will not be applied to the scene (for efficiency reasons so that, for instance, you could write a high performance game that did not use CSS processing).  So CSS processing for Text is not necessarily required and, if used, is limited in its scope.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways:

1. Add css style to the Text's instance.
2. Use Label instead.

I recommend using Label instead of Text.

Comment: Using Label works well, shows as disabled unlike text